# How to Export this final product with Sound Animation to Unity?

Tags: animation, export, unity, fcurves

Is there a way to export this animation into Unity, with all the material settings (especially the water droplets on the apple) AND movement intact from the "bake sound to f-curve" feature?

Here was the tutorial I basically followed to build this product: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8RHRNZQEuE

Comment: I'm confused, where is the apple? You can't export modifiers other than armature, They will be applied before export. Bake to f-curve works, but you'd have to do that to a channel Unity  understand, either loc, rot or scale. To give you more information, I need to know where the apple and the droplets are.

Comment: Thank you @FrederikSteinmetz , sorry for the confusion, I was also working off of this beginners tutorial with the apples: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOm2K9jOZLI  I was able to export the droplets over to Unity, although I was hoping to retain the same appearance after the export, but looks like that's not possible.